# Return 0 statement?

Tags: c++, fork

The return 0 statement returns the value of 0 to the operating system or to the process that generated the executable?

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    fork();
    return 0;
}
```

The second process (child) created with fork() returns the value of 0 to the process that generated it (father) or operating system?

Answer (score 4):

If the parent invokes `wait(&status)`, then the zero is written into status (assuming the child does not experience a system error or is terminated by a signal). In the case you give (again, assuming no errors), the child is inherited by init, which waits on it, gets the zero, and ignores it.  To clarify, suppose the child exits before the parent: in that case, the child terminates and the zero is maintained by the system in the process table while the child is in the zombie state.  Then the parent terminates and all of its zombie children are inherited by init.  Then init waits for the child, allowing the process table entry to be removed by the system.  If the parent terminates first, then all of its children (either zombie or non-zombie) are inherited by init while the parent is terminating.  Then the child terminates, enters the zombie state (for a very short time, since init will schedule very soon ) until init waits on it, discards the zero, and the child's entry in the process table is removed.

In other words, the zero is stored in the process table until the parent waits on it.  If the original parent doesn't wait, the new parent will.  The new parent is almost always init, but there are techniques (eg ptrace) which may cause a different process to become the new parent.